# What does the two number mean in Github contributor graph page?

Tags: github, wiki

[Example](https://github.com/tshi0912/city-picker/graphs/contributors).

In this page, for each contributor, there is a text description just like:

`fengyuanchen 54 commits / 53,994 ++ / 39,917 --`

What does the two number `53,994 ++ / 39,917 --` and the signs `++, --` mean? I couldn't find any tips in github help or google.

I guess they are something like stackoverflow's reputation meachanism, I was wonder how to achive such reputation in github, what's the rules?

Answer (score 12):

**No**, reputation meachanism.

`53,994 ++` green colour indicate current user added lines and `39,917 --` red colour indicate current user remove or replace lines.

Comment: Thanks. But I still wanna know if there is any reference links for this?

Comment: I just see in the page right side, there is a dropdown list for `Filter contributions`, include three options  `Additions`, `Deletions`, `Commits`, this made me understand.

Answer (score 8):

These present the user's contribution in terms of added/removed lines.

Comment: I think it must be added or removed characters. I have projects that are a few hundred lines long, but the contributions has e.g. 10,000 ++ 7,000 -- which is many times the number of lines in the repo